# Remote(WAN) kafka client cannot write data to kafka which is in LAN

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-zookeeper, kafka-producer-api

I'm trying to  configure advertised.listener to receive data from remote host.
Producer running on remote host and  sends data to kafka. Kafka running in our LAN. Also there is a port mapping: public_ip:9092--->10.10.128.125:9792. Here, 9092 is external port which maps to 9792 which is kafka broker port.
Bellow is the configuration from server.properties file

```
listeners=INTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9792,EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9092
advertised.listeners=INTERNAL://10.10.128.125:9792,EXTERNAL://external_ip:9092
listener.security.protocol.map=INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
inter.broker.listener.name=INTERNAL
```

Metadata which was sent from kafka to remote kafka client  contains broker's internal  ip and port, I can see this from producer log

```
DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Updated cluster metadata updateVersion 2 to MetadataCache{clusterId='2YXDmEjfR1iP1R1pUDM6qw', nodes={1=10.10.128.125:9792 (id: 1 rack: null)}, partitions=[PartitionMetadata(error=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE, partition=Kafka-9, leader=Optional.empty, leaderEpoch=Optional[57], replicas=2, isr=2, offlineReplicas=2)}

08:23:43.835 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Initiating connection to node 10.10.128.125:9792 (id: 1 rack: null) using address /10.10.128.125
```

So, producer sends data using internal ip and port from remote host. As a result I cannot receive the data.
Why producer receives metadata with internal ip and port, even after configuring advertised.listener?
Any advice would be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

What is your bootstrap.servers property set to? You have to set bootstrap.servers to one of the broker's external ip:port

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Manish Bhatt, thank you for the response, yes, bootstrap.servers points to broker's external ip and port. Producer would not get metadata from kafka, if I point internal ip and port. So producer receives metadata which contains internal broker ip and port. Then using this internal ip producer tries to send data back to broker which is not accessible by internal ip and port. This article: https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/  explains  communication between producer and broker